# Drop down list data bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two drop down lists. Whan I select some item from first ddl, in second I get some other values to choose. I have a problem, because when I pick some value from second ddl and then choose standard value in first ddl, after page loads there is still old value of the secon ddl.
What should I do when I want to set default value in second ddl BEFORE the page is loads?

EDIT:
Adding the code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GetFunctions();
        GetTeams();
        LocateCities();
    }
    else
    {
        if (ddlFunctions.Text.ToString() == "All  Functions")
        {
            ddlTeams.Text = " All  Teams";
            LocateCities();
        }
        else
        {
            LocateCities();
        }
    }
}

protected void ddlFunctions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlFunctions.Text.ToString() == "All  Functions")
    {
        Teams.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Teams.Visible = true;
        GetTeams();
    }
}
```

Binding to the ddls are in GetFunctions() (first ddl) and GetTeams() (second ddl). The only problem is when I have some value selected in second ddl and change value in first ddl (the old value from second ddl goes to stored procedure which cause that LocateCities() method returns 0 values). I would like to have default value All Teams were passed to procedure when I change value in first ddl. I hope I explained exerything. If no, please let me know.

Comment: is your event (which loads item to second ddl)not executing when you select an item in the first DDL ?

Comment: are you using postback?

Comment: Please share some code. Otherwise it's impossible to find the solution to your problem.

Comment: @Learner: Yes I set AutoPostBack="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SelectedIndexChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) of the first to set the default value on the second.

Like this:

```
void foo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    bar.SelectedIndex = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex;
    // or whatever your logic is. Merry coding.
}
```

Comment: I tried what You posted. I added the line: ddlFunctions.SelectedIndex = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex; but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to supply your own logic. You've got to redo the databindings or filtering of the second list before that as well. The code I wrote there is just to suggest using the event, if you just paste it verbatim it's prone to go wrong.